# Solving parabolic pde with piecewise-constant coefficients with Feynman-Kac

Tags: partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

Consider the partial differential equation:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t) + \mu(x,t) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,t) + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2(x,t) \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}(x,t) - V(x,t) u(x,t) + f(x,t) = 0$$
defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R}_+$ and $t \in [0,T]$, subject to the terminal condition:
$$u(x,T) = \psi(x)$$
where $\mu, \sigma, \psi, V, f$ are known functions, $T$ is a parameter, and $u: \mathbb{R}_+\times[0,T] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the unknown. The pde admits a Feynman-Kac representation, which is standard and can be found for instance [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula).

When the coefficients $\mu, \sigma, V, f$ do not depend on time and are piecewise constants over the partition $[0,c), [c, \infty)$, for instance of the form
$\mu(x) = \mu_1 1_{\{x > c\}} + \mu_2 1_{\{x \leq c\}}$ ($1_{\{x>c\}}$ takes value 1 if $x>c$ and zero otherwise), one could solve the pde piecewisely by finding two different solutions and then pasting them together. An example of the above can be found in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172463/existence-of-a-parabolic-pde-with-indicator-function-coefficient).

Is the same true for the FK representation? Is it possible to find piecewisely two representations separately for $x \in [0,c)$ and $x \in [c, \infty)$ and then put them together?

Comment: maybe related to the method of images?

Comment: I'm not familiar with it, can you elaborate on your idea?

Comment: I've had a surprisingly hard time to find a good reference. Basically the idea is similar to the "electrostatic" method of images: To find the "probability" of reaching a point with a specific boundary condition, you solve for 2 different random walkers, one on each side of the barrier, and consider a weighted sum that fits the the boundary condition. For example, if the b.c. was absorbing, you would subtract. In the case of a change in coefficients,  solve each side with the right b.c. and combine. I suspect that reflecting b.c. is what is needed. This is all speculation, so no answer posting